# Android SQLiteStatement: how to bind numeric (Date, BigDecimal)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Android SQLiteStatement: how to bind numeric (Date, BigDecimal)?

SQLiteStatement has

```
bindNull
bindLong
bindDouble
bindString
bindBlob
```

For java.util.Date and java.util.BigDecimal, they are mapped to Numeric as column type. But there is no bindNumeric(...) method. Which method for binding these types?

Answer (score 0):

#### Date

Date could be bound as long or a String depending on the value. The former if it's an integer representation of the date, the latter if it's a more human readable date. It may be wise to use the formats supported by SQLite's Date/Time functions as per :-

> **Time Strings**
>
> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> - YYYY-MM-DD
> - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> - HH:MM HH:MM:SS
> - HH:MM:SS.SSS
> - now
> - DDDDDDDDDD

[Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

#### Big Decimal

You can downgrade to double and bind as a double (noting potential loss), bind as a string (note type affinity comes into play i.e. column affinity should be TEXT) or use two longs one for the scale and one for the un-scaled value.

You should refer to [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)